# After installing go and setting my path, I am still getting an error

Tags: bash, go

After installing golang according to the instructions on the golang website, I set the path as it said to by using `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` and whenever I use the command `$HOME/go` it says `bash: /home/ken/go: No such file or directory`

I can verify go is installed and I even reset my computer to make sure the changes took place.  Does anybody know what I can do to resolve this issue?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Does `/home/ken/go` exist though?

Comment: how do I check that?  I thought that was standard unix file path.

Comment: It is. Just try `cd /home/ken/go`...

Comment: No such file or directory... So what do I do? I'm new to all this stuff and I just copy what they say to do on their website

Comment: Start with `mkdir /home/ken/go` and wait for your next problem :)

Comment: Note that the instructions do say: Create your workspace directory, $HOME/go. (If you'd like to use a different directory, you will need to set the GOPATH environment variable.)

Comment: But why doesn't /home/ken/go already exist? I thought that was standard?  Also, I thought the latest version of go is 1.13.6 but mine is telling me I have 1.10.4, I already uninstalled and reinstalled the 1.13.6 package but it is still saying I only have 1.10.4...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206553/discussion-between-see-sharper-and-kenneth-boelter).

Comment: @KennethBoelter : I don't use Go, but from the docs, I conclued that `$HOME/go` is the default [GOPATH](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH).  If you want the go folder at a different location, just change it with `export GOPATH=the-location-where-you-find-your-happiness`

Answer (score 1):

As per the instructions on the Go installation page, you do need to manually create the go folder:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir go
cd go
```

Then create your first go program: https://gobyexample.com/hello-world
And run with `go run hello-world.go`. Should be good ;)